# Как в библиотеку ключ вставить из одного .txt а значение из другого?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть определенные данные которые приходят в текстовых документах. Для примера представим что в первом приходит "Один", во втором "1", думаю понятно. Далее эти данные необходимо сравнивать с другими. То есть нужно в библиотеку вставить ключ из одного .txt , а значение из другого. Как это сделать? Спасибо.

Comment: А проблема-то в чём? Читаете данные из файлов и вставляете куда нужно.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('yourfile1.txt') as f:
    keys = f.readlines()

with open('yourfile2.txt') as f2:
    values = f2.readlines()

your_dictionary = {}

for i in range(len(keys)):
    your_dictionary[keys[i]] = values[i]
```

Comment: Может быть я не так что то делаю, но повторил ваш код точь в точь, у меня выдает ошибку во второй строчке

Comment: @Tryr Какая ошибка?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 2, in <module>
    keys = f.readlines()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\encodings\cp1251.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 72: character maps to <undefined>


------------------
(program exited with code: 1)

Для продолжения нажмите любую клавишу . . .